# TMS AdvSmoothMenu1 Item click

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

It seems AdvSmoothMenu1 does not have itemindex property. I am trying to do :

```
case AdvSmoothMenu1.ItemIndex of 
0: begin
```

...
but it seems there is no such option. So how do I tell my application what to do on different items click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TAdvSmoothMenu.OnItemClick` event:

```
procedure TForm1.AdvSmoothMenu1ItemClick(Sender: TObject; 
  ItemIndex: Integer);
begin
  case ItemIndex of
    0: HandleItemZeroClick;
    1: HandleItemOneClick;
  end;
end;
```